# How to tell Click to always show option defaults

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

In Python's [Click](https://palletsprojects.com/p/click/) package I can define a default for an option:

```
@click.option("--count", default=1, help="Number of greetings.")
```

and I can specify that the default should be shown in the help:

```
@click.option("--count", default=1, help="Number of greetings.", show_default=True)
```

If I have many options

```
@click.option("--count-a", default=1, help="...")
@click.option("--count-b", default=2, help="...")
@click.option("--count-c", default=4, help="...")
.
.
.
```

how can I tell Click generically to *always* show  defaults in the help (without explicitly adding `show_default=True` to the parameter list of each individual option)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pretty easily define your own function for that like:

#### Code

```
def click_option(*args, **kwargs):
    return click.option(*args, show_default=True, **kwargs)
```

Or if you want to override `show_default` in individual option decorators:

```
def click_option(*args, **kwargs):
    if not 'show_default' in kwargs:
        kwargs.update({'show_default': True})
    return click.option(*args, **kwargs)
```

#### Test Code:

```
import click

def click_option(*args, **kwargs):
    if not 'show_default' in kwargs:
        kwargs.update({'show_default': True})
    return click.option(*args, **kwargs)

@click.command()
@click_option('--an-option', default='The Default')
def cli(an_option):
    """An Awesome CLI"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli(['--help'])
```

#### Results:

```
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

  An Awesome CLI

Options:
  --an-option TEXT  [default: The Default]
  --help            Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Thanks. (I was hoping for a "Click-native" way with a parameter in, say, the `@command` decorator, but this probably doesn't exist.)

Comment: Done. Accepted it as well.

Answer (score 21):

The probably most suited way to do that is by changing the context settings in the `@click.command` decorator. Like this:

```
@click.command("cli", context_settings={'show_default': True})
@click.option("-x")
@click.option("-y", default="Custom Y")
@click.option("-z", default="Custom Z", help="Value of Z.")
def cli(x, y, z):
    """Test changin context settings"""
    return "OK"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

This prints the following:

```
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

  Test changing context settings

Options:
  -x TEXT
  -y TEXT  [default: Custom Y]
  -z TEXT  Value of Z.  [default: Custom Z]
  --help   Show this message and exit.  [default: False]
```

Comment: Is there a way to disable `show_default` for a specific option? `@click.option(..., show_default=False)` doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Fixed since click version [8.1.0](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/changes/#version-8-1-0): `Command.show_default overrides Context.show_default, instead of the other way around. #1963`